# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, django, linux

Please Help me to install Django on virtual enviroment
My terminal throw this error

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlparse' Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.`

Comment: The answer is in your question.  Check the permissions for directory ... and fix them.

Comment: How you are creating virtual environment ? Did your virtual environment `activated` ? Is  your  `python` in the `PATH` ?

Comment: Suppose you wish to install a package say `pandas`,  you'd do `pip install pandas` but to do with elevated permissions you have to do `pip install pandas --user`

Comment: make sure you `activate` your environment before installing the new libraries.

Comment: I activate the environment using `source name/bin/activate`